# casting object and checking if it is instance of casted class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to cast an `Object` to a class using `as` keyword but when I check if it is instance of class it returns false. Can someone explain why it is this way and is there any was to cast to the class and check if it is instance of the class ?

Sample code :

```
class A {
    id: string;
    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id
    }
}

const a = { id: '1' } as A
const b = new A('1')

console.log(a instanceof A); // false
console.log(b instanceof A) // true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` in TS means that you expect the `object` to be an instance of a class. In Java or C#, you may put `A a = s as A` where `s` must be of super-class of A. You can't put it `A a = s as B`.

Here, as you put, `{ id: '1' }` is an instance of class `Object`. `A` is a custom class, you provide, with a field `id`. `new A('1')` gives an instance of `A`.

Why is variable `a` not the instance of `A` ? You found `a` has the same shape to `new A('1')` which you assign to `b`.

It's just shape. Shape is nothing! You should care how `a` and `b` are created.

`a = { id: '1' }` is equivalent to `a = new Object(); a.id = '1'`. `a` is `Object`, not `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Type does not exist in runtime. So `a` is an object and not an instance of class A.

Look up the compiled javascript code at the [Play ground](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQJYBMBc0IBcAndAOwHMBuFNYAexIMIFdh9bCAKLXR0sgSkTU0afAAt0EAHRZoAXgyZh0AL5I1SOg3zQw8xItwByAIxHVumLE30C0AEb6SAUwDucDqaP8kNhrRBnKRBaMg49UgIwEmBnWgAzOH4KaAB6VOh4sBAIZz8IAKCQsMdI-GjYhKS0jKImZyA)

Comment: do you mean `{id: '1'}` happens in runtime whereas `new A('1')` is not ?

Comment: `new A('1')` ==> create an instance of class A. `as A`: you cast un object to **type** A in compile time, but it does not change the fact that it is not an instance of class A in runtime. It's the same thing as writing `const a = '3' as unknown as number;`: you force `a` to type number in compile time, but it does not change the fact that in runtime, it is still a string.